# Como puedo recargar un componente en ionic 3

Tags: ionic, ionic3, ciclo-de-vida

Necesito obtener los datos y ejecuto una función que si me los carga en la vista pero para eso tengo que hacer un window.location.reload() y no es la mejor opcion para una app móvil, alguien sabe como puedo recargar?, Ya use los ciclos de vida pero aun así no logro que funcione, necesito algo asi como NgOnInit de Angular. Leí que tambien aplicaba para Ionic,pero obtuve el mismo resultado negativo... Espero puedan ayudarme.

````
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.

      let prueba = this._us.cargar_storage()
      prueba.then(key => {
        // console.log(key); 
        if(key){
          this.rootPage=TabsPage;
          this.menuCtrl.enable(true);

          this.entro(); //aqui obtengo los datos pero se necesita recargar la página
        }else{
          console.log("aqui no");          
          this.rootPage=LoginPage;
          if(this.rootPage==LoginPage){
            this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
          }
        }```
````

Comment: agrega el fragmento de codigo completo no se puede entender mucho con lo que suministras

Comment: quizás te venga bien está web donde explica el ciclo de vida de los componentes de **Ionic 3** : [webCicloVida](https://blog.ng-classroom.com/blog/tips/lifecycle-ionic/)